# serialize deserialize message in intraprocess publishing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone.
i have one publisher that publishes data on a topic, and one subscriber that receives message from that topic. both publisher and subscriber are on the same node. ros intraprocess publishing indicates that if used shared_ptr serialization/deserialization will be ignored, for testing, i use other PC and connect to running roscore on robot and with rostopic echo, i can see publishing data. therefore i think serialization and deserialization happens. furthermore rostopic in the same PC shows publishing data.
i think when i publish with shared_ptr, other nodes can't see the data, if they can, serialization/deserialization is being happend. please explain if i'm wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163621/serialize-deserialize-message-in-intraprocess-publishing/) by [MohsenTamiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/17846/mohsentamiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

serialization/deserialization will only be skipped if the connection is within the same node.

If you use rostopic echo or some other different program of course serialization must happen, otherwise it cannot work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MohsenTamiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/17846/mohsentamiz/) on 2014-05-11**:
Thanks for your reply.
Is it mean subscriber determines if a message should serialize or not? In class reference of Publish of ROS documentation message I found three methods that always do serialize for example this method:
void ros::Publisher::publish( const boost::shared_ptr< M > &  message)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-05-12**:
It's handled internally. This is a special case.

**Comment by [MohsenTamiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/17846/mohsentamiz/) on 2014-05-12**:
As ROS class reference publisher said,"This version of publish will allow fast intra-process message-passing in the future", the shared_ptr transmision will be added in future. this feature is very important in my project, and i want to be sure about this capability. Is there any way to check this?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-05-12**:
If you are relying on fast inner-node publications that work via topics http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet is probably what you are looking for.